# Key stuck in Security Door

Tags: doors, lock, security

My home door is a Security Door using this type of mechanism [image: door]. The lock itself is about 20 years old and i now have a key stuck in it.
The key is on the inside and will rotate almost 90° in both directions.
I tried spraying some lubricant (don't have graphite handy) in the lock but the key won't budge.

This is the first time it happened, i've already tried pushing another key or screwdriver on the other side but no luck

If any of you has any tips i'll greatly appreciate it as it's 9PM and i'll have to sleep with an unlocked door :)

The actual mechanism brand is Mottura but it looks really similar to the one in the picture.

Also, the key seems to be in the default position. Turning counterclockwise will move the opening shaft slightly, but turning clockwise has no effect.

Comment: Best guess is that one of the pins has shifted, and if that's it, you probably won't be able to lock the door. However, you could and get the key out by  tapping it from the side with something like the butt of a screwdriver while applying turning pressure. (I strongly suggest you not lock yourself in and try to remove the key, unless you have an alternate exit.)

Comment: Given the complexity of that door, I would strongly recommend contacting the manufacturer and asking them who in your area is factory-certified to work on it. Speaking as a locksmith, I could probably figure it out but I'm not sure I would trust most folks to do so and I wouldn't be surprised to find I had to call for help.

Comment: What's the brand/model of your unit? The image says "METAL SYSTEMS", but that may just be a picture you found, not your actual mechanism.

Comment: Are the four bolts projecting from the door far enough to get a firm grip on them with a pliers?

Comment: Unfortunately not, they move about 1mm out.

Comment: Ah, well. Sometimes you can unstiick this kind of lock by rattling the bolts in and out while turning the key back and forth near its counterclockwise limit - but you need to grip the bolts to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you get the key out, you really can't trust the lock any more. Next time it jams, you could be locked in.

I think for tonight you should secure the door with a couple of wedges, and call a locksmith in the morning.